What are the reasons for internet exchanges to use publicly routable networks?
Internet exchanges like AMS-IX or DE-CIX use publicly routable IPv4 and IPv6 networks on their peering LANs. For example, in case of AMS-IX, the networks are 80.249.208.0/21 and 2001:7f8:1::/64 and each member of the IX gets one or more addresses from those networks to establish BGP sessions with other members.
Why are the internet exchanges using publicly routable networks? I guess one reason is to avoid the possible address conflicts. For example, a single router might be connected to DE-CIX and also to AMS-IX and if both exchanges happen to use a same private network on their peering LAN, then there would be address conflicts.
Are there any other reasons for internet exchanges to use publicly routable networks?

A couple of things spring to mind.

By default in BGP, the "BGP nexthop" is the address of the router in the peer AS. So the exchange subnet is carried in the IGPs of the peers, which would greatly increase the risk of address conflicts if private IPs were used. It is possible to use "next-hop self" to avoid this, but that does bring some downsides.
Exchange point IPs may appear as the source of ICMP messages. These may be filtered if they are sourced from private IPs.

It's also worth keeping in mind, that IP addresses were not meant to be a scarce resource, they only became one as a result of the internet growing way beyond what it's founders could have reasonably imagined.
